# Meaning of text on poster

Tags: translation

For many years ago I went to China and bought a poster. Now i really wonder what the charcters mean. I tried downloading some programs, but I couldn't translate the text.

I understand this is not a translation service. Anyway I'll have to give it a shot. Or else I'm never going to find out what it means.

[image: Chineese text1] [image: Chineese text2]

Comment: The first one is 竹报平安 ('home letter reporting safety', meaning blessing for peace), the second is 丁亥年 (the 24th year in Chinese sexagenary cycle, 1887/1947/2007/2067/... are all 丁亥年).

Comment: I bought the poster January 2008 som it seems resonable the poster is dated to 2007.

Answer (score 3):

竹报平安 (zhúbào-píng’ān) = send a letter home saying that all is well

丁亥年 (dīnghài nián) = 2007 (or 1947, 1887, …)

Comment: The full pictures is of 2 pandas and some bambos. The Image is attached to a "stick". And you can roll it around the stick and into a scroll. So i think you're right. It seems made for sending home as a scroll/message. Very happy with the response. Thanks too all. xiè xie :P

Answer (score 1):

Picture 1

X（can not recognize）报（traditional Chinese）平安。
means  x sends safeness， or  x sending safeness。

Picture 2
can“t  read it.

Answer (score 1):

竹报平安 (zhúbào-píng’ān) (bamboo for fine)，this is a traditional phrase, frequently used when you are away from family for long, and sending a mail back home to tell your family everything is fine for you.

丁亥年 is a traditional style of recording years. There are 10 marks for sky (天干), and 12 marks for earth (地支), and they are grouped one by one, which is 60 groups (干支纪年). 丁 is the 4th of 天干, and 亥 is 12th of 地支.

Also you may have heard that Chinese people have a property called 属相 (shǔxiang), which is an animal standing for the year the person was born. There are 12 animals, paired with 12 地支. 亥 is paired with pig.

Comment: How come 10 * 12 = 60 ?

Comment: it's the least common multiple, not the direct product.

Comment: @user2550062 
It is math problem. Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple